# How do you find the closest solutions to an equation, in which the variables are bounded by their sets?

Tags: number-theory, optimization, real-numbers, integers

The equation that I am working with is the following:

$A + \frac{x}{y} = D $

where A belongs to a set of integers, x and y belong to a set of whole numbers ranging from 0 to 10, and D belongs to a set of all real numbers. The goal is to find the closest value of A, x and y within their sets, for a given value of D.

**My attempt**

I believe I have "solved" the problem, but only graphically. To illustrate, I will use a specific example. Let's say that the given value of D is the famous Euler's number $e \approx 2.71828...$

Therefore, we arrive at the following:

$A + \frac{x}{y} = e \approx 2.718281828...$

Finding A is pretty easy, it is simply going to be the first digit of the decimal. Therefore, $A = 2$. So our equation reduces down to the following:

$\frac{x}{y} = e - 2 \approx 0.71828...$

Re-arranging this equation, we get a straight line going through the origin:

$x = (e - 2)y \approx 0.71828...x$

I will be graphing this on Desmos.com. This is the part where the graphical analysis takes place. The steps to take are the following to solve the question:

- Graphically set the borders of the equation (by setting $x = 0, y = 0, x = 10, y = 10$). Then, set the steps on x and y axis to 1.
- Draw the graph $x = (e - 2)y \approx 0.71828...x$
- Mark the whole number pairs closest to the line with dots (here I used purple dots)
- Your solution is the dot closest to the line (here marked by the circle)

[image]

As you can see, this method concludes that $(x,y) \rightarrow (5,7)$ which seems *reasonably* true. If you check it, you'll find $2 + 5/7 \approx 2.714285714... \approx e = 2.718281828$. However doing all these graphical steps is long and cumbersome. I am looking for a formula that I can use to compute $A, x$ and $y$ directly for any given $D$ value.

Please let me know if there is any confusion with this question, I am happy to clear any doubts!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction